# Automate clicking button using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click

I would like to automate clicking on "Refresh" button (See image "Refreshbutton") using python and selenium. I have tried to locate the button using xpath, id, class name but each time, I get the NoSuchElement exception, i.e. it cannot find the element. How can I locate the Refresh button? I don't care if it is by xpath, id or any other means. Thanks in advance!

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lQVB.png)

[RefreshButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpaGh.png)

[Find by XPATH try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZZKx.png)

[Find By ID try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNcD.png)

[Class Name try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6uER.png)

[Python Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF9uW.png)

Comment: Could you link the website you're trying to get the data from

Comment: Unfortunately I cant as I am accessing a camera that is part of a robotic vision system. The link is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be the id/xpath but the presence of the button on the page. If the click is executed before the HTML page is fully loaded, the element might not be here yet. To make sure, you can use the WebDriverWait as follow:

```
element_xpath = '//*[@id="btnRefreshCameraList"]'
wait_time = 15  # wait for page to load for max. 15 seconds
WebDriverWait(
    driver, wait_time).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath))
    )
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
```

Didn't have access to your site, so I couldn't try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I am waiting before I try to locate the button. I have edited my post with my python code snippet, please have a look.